# The maximum value of a microphone input in a list is wrong c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get Mic input and convert it into a float number. When I print the Maximum float number of a list, it prints me unlimited times the same number (it prints all the time while pressing "T"). I just want it to print the biggest number in the list of a microphone input just one number. The method for calculating it is in "Maximum_Level method"

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Linq;
public class MicInputs : MonoBehaviour
{
public enum micActivation
{
    HoldToSpeak,

}
public micActivation micControl;
private float sample_max = 0.0f;

public static float MicLoudFloat;
public List<float> recorded_values = new List<float>();
public List<float> final_values = new List<float>();
private string theMicroDevice;
AudioClip recordOfClips;
//microphone initialization
void MicroInitialization()
{
    if (theMicroDevice == null) theMicroDevice = 
Microphone.devices[0];
    recordOfClips = Microphone.Start(theMicroDevice, true, 999, 
44100);
}

void StopMicrophone()
{
    Microphone.End(theMicroDevice);
    Maximum_Level(); // Collect the final sample
    MicLoudFloat = sample_max;
    print(MicLoudFloat);

}

void Awake()
{
    recordOfClips = AudioClip.Create("nameOfClip", 128, 2, 1000, 
true);
}
//AudioClip clip = myRecordedOrOwnClip;
//reate(string name, int lengthSamples, int channels, int frequency, 
bool stream,
//_sampleWindow = clip.samples;
//AudioClip _clipRecord = new AudioClip();
//AudioClip _clipRecord = AudioClip.Create("nameOfClip", 128, 2, 1, 
true);
int samplesWindows = 128;



//=========THIS IS THE START OF THE METHOD========


// get data from microphone into audioclip
float Maximum_Level()
{

    float[] waveData = new float[samplesWindows];
    int micPosition = Microphone.GetPosition(null) - (samplesWindows 
+1); // null means the first microphone
    if (micPosition < 0) return 0;
    recordOfClips.GetData(waveData, micPosition);
    // Getting a peak on the last 128 samples
    for (int i = 0; i < samplesWindows; i++)
    {
        float wavePeak = waveData[i] * waveData[i];
        if (wavePeak > sample_max)
        {
            sample_max = wavePeak;
        }
    }
    return sample_max;
    //float maximum_level = 0;
    //float[] waveData = new float[samplesWindows];
    //int micPosition = Microphone.GetPosition(null) - 
(samplesWindows + 1); // null means the first microphone
    //if (micPosition < 0) return 0;
    //recordOfClips.GetData(waveData, micPosition);
    //// Getting a peak on the last 128 samples
    //for (int i = 0; i < samplesWindows; i++)
    //{
    //    float wavePeak = waveData[i] * waveData[i];
    //    if (maximum_level < wavePeak)
    //    {
    //        maximum_level = wavePeak;
    //        recorded_values.Add(maximum_level);
    //    }
    //}

    //float max = recorded_values.Max();
    ////print(max);
    //return max;


    //print(maximum_level);
    //return maximum_level;
}

//=========THIS IS THE END OF THE METHOD========



void Update()
{
    if (micControl == micActivation.HoldToSpeak)
    {
        if (Microphone.IsRecording(theMicroDevice) && 
Input.GetKey(KeyCode.T) == false)
            StopMicrophone();
        //
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.T)){ //Push to talk
            MicroInitialization();

        }
        //
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.T)){
            StopMicrophone();


        }

    }

Maximum_Level();
    // levelMax equals to the highest normalized value power 2, a 
small number because < 1
    // pass the value to a static var so we can access it from 
anywhere


    //print(MicLoudFloat);
}

bool isItInitialized;

// start mic when scene starts
void OnEnable()
{
    MicroInitialization();
    isItInitialized = true;
}

//stop mic when loading a new level or quit application
void OnDisable()
{
    StopMicrophone();
}

void OnDestroy()
{
    StopMicrophone();
}


// detects if the mic gets started & stopped when application gets 
focused
void OnApplicationFocus(bool focus)
{
    if (focus)
    {
        //Debug.Log("Focus");

        if (!isItInitialized)
        {
            //Debug.Log("Init Mic");
            MicroInitialization();
            isItInitialized = true;
        }
    }
    if (!focus)
    {
        //Debug.Log("Pause");
        StopMicrophone();
        //Debug.Log("Stop Mic");
        isItInitialized = false;

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are re-defining `maximum_level` every time you call the function so every frame you are treating the maximum level as 0 for every `samplesWindows`. Meaning every frame, `MicLoudFloat` is going to receive the value of the highest level of that frame's sample. 
MicLoudFloat would look like this across several frames:

```
0, 0, 0.2, 1.5, 0.4, 0, 0
```

If you want to know the current maximum, you'll need to compare `MicLoudFloat` with the results of `Maximum_Level();` and apply it to `MicLoudFloat` only if it is larger.

eg

```
float newValue = Maximum_Level();
MicLoudFloat = (newValue > MicLoudFloat) ? newValue : MicLoudFloat;
print(MicLoudFloat);
// 0, 0, 0.2, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5
```

Alternately, if you only wanted to print when `MicLoudFloat` has changed, you could do something like:

```
float newValue = Maximum_Level();
if (newValue > MicLoudFloat)
{
    MicLoudFloat = newValue;
    print(MicLoudFloat); 
    // 0, 0.2, 1.5
}
```

**EDIT---**

If you only want the largest value of the entire set, you have to wait until you know that the set is complete before assigning.

This can be achieved by instead doing

```
MicLoudFloat = recorded_values.Max();
```

Inside the `StopMicrophone` method. But you'd need to clear out the list of `recorded_values` each time you started the microphone again.

You can also do away with all the intermediary lists and assignment like so:

```
public static float MicLoudFloat;
private float sample_max = 0;

// ...
void StopMicrophone()
{
    Microphone.End(theMicroDevice);
    Maximum_Level(); // Collect the final sample
    MicLoudFloat = sample_max;
    print(MicLoudFloat);
    // 1.5
}

// ...

float Maximum_Level()
{
    float[] waveData = new float[samplesWindows];
    int micPosition = Microphone.GetPosition(null) - (samplesWindows + 
    1); // null means the first microphone
    if (micPosition < 0) return 0;
    recordOfClips.GetData(waveData, micPosition);
    // Getting a peak on the last 128 samples
    for (int i = 0; i < samplesWindows; i++)
    {
        float wavePeak = waveData[i] * waveData[i];
        if (wavePeak > sample_max)
        {
            sample_max= wavePeak
        }
    }
    return sample_max;
 }

// ...

void Update()
{
    // ...

    Maximum_Level();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It looks way better now. However, it still prints a few numbers.(0.005; 0.0096; 0.010, etc). How to make it to print only the largest number (1  number/float only) due to later I will need that number to convert into a radius in a game. So, I need only 1 final number which is the biggest one of each input.

Comment: Well it's impossible to know the largest value of an incomplete set. What you could do is wait until `StopMicrophone` is called to return the last-known largest value of `MicLoudFloat`.

Comment: I am trying to place the code you suggested into Update() method where the microphone is initialized when T is pressed. Then, I am trying to return the MicLoudFloat in the same Update() method but when StopMicrophone() method is called. It prints me 0s all the time. I guess I am doing it wrong. What did you mean by "wait until StopMicrophone is called to return the last-known largest value of MicLoudFloat"? Do I need to create a new method with the previously suggested code? Then, where exactly do I return MicLoudFloat when the Microphone is stopped?

Comment: @optimus see my updated code, you still want to call `Maximum_Level()` in the `Update()` method, however you don't assign the return value to `MicLoudFloat` until `StopMicrophone()` is called. So long as the microphone is collecting data, you don't know if you have the loudest value or not. The only way to know that is to wait until the microphone is done collecting data, then you can store the result of the loudest value in `MicLoudFloat`

Comment: @ Enfyve Please, see my updated question. I tried to use your last suggestion and in addition I tried my variations, it simply prints me 0 when I press T ( for mic input).

Comment: @optimus you still want to be calling `Maximum_Level` from inside your `Update` method, just don't assign its return value to anything. Also something I missed, you'll want to initialize your `sample_max` with a value of 0. `private float sample_max = 0.0f;`

Comment: @ Enfyve Thank you so much. I updated and posted my code. I have 2 more issues. 1. It prints  2 same numbers per input. 2. If I yell into the mic, the maximum value is 1. It does not go up

Comment: @optimus if it's printing more than once, then `StopMicrophone()` is being called more than once, you'll want to continue debugging to find out why (I assume it should only be called once, if that's the case, perhaps at the beginning of `StopMicrophone` you can check if `isItInitialized == false` and return immediately if so. As for the second issue, it's getting into a different topic, I recommend you ask that question separately.

Comment: @ Enfyve Thank you so much for your help!